# Best approach for saving data from application forms and REST API in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I will be creating an application in Oracle Apex where users can add data to the database through an Apex form and through a provided REST API. Each field will undergo validation, and some of them will have dependencies on each other. What would be the best approach for storing and validating such data, without creating separate solutions for forms and separate ones for the REST API?
I have been thinking about adding a transition table where data will be stored and validations will be performed before the final save.

Comment: We don't know enough to know, but consider building the business logic/rules and validation INTO your  REST APIs. That way if you decide to build additional front ends, you don't have to redo the work in say your mobile app in GO, you just call the REST APIs as before and you're good to go.

Comment: you should also consider putting the biz logic into the plsql code, and then have your rest apis simply be calls of those plsql apis